# FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException' not found

Tags: symfony

I use sonata admin/userBundle and FosUserBundle but when I check the profile page "/profile",I get this strange error :

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException' not found in /var/www/project/vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Sonata/UserBundle/Block/ProfileMenuBlockService.php line 97
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add some class dependencies (eg. "use .."). Check if you correctly import every used class in `ProfileMenuBlockService.php`.

Comment: I got the same problem, not sure if it is a PHP or Symfony bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error a few weeks ago.  First time I ever heard of a flattened exception.

I have a BaseController class with two derived controller classes (AccountController and PersonController)

Each of the derived controllers had a createModel() method with different arguments.  I decided to clean things up by adding a createModel() method to the BaseController.  I started with PersonController and all seemed well.

I then cleared the development cache and suddenly got the flattened exception error.  Something in the cache creation process had determined that the arguments to AccountController::createModel() did not match the arguments in BaseController::createModel().  PHP did not care since AccountController was never calling BaseController::createModel.  But the cache builder was.  Fixing the arguments solved the problem.

The question does not give us much to go on but you might take a look at any inheritance type changes that you may have made.

Comment: can you see my Edit in my first message

Comment: The new error message is a completely different issue.  I'd suggest starting another question since the title of this one is now very inaccurate.  Hint: it is a template problem.  I suspect you may have been copy/pasting things with really understanding.  Try searching the net for fields.html.twig